# adding two factor authentication on to cots?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I know, in general, what two factor authentication (2FA) is and how it works.  I also know it's coded into the application that needs access.  What I'm wondering is:  has anyone ever come across or devised a method of using 2FA for a COTS (commercial, off-the-shelf) program?

Here's a scenario:  I've got product X, and to work, X needs a port on a firewall to be open so that it can access a server inside the firewall.  X does not have 2FA.  But I want to put 2FA into effect so that only after the authentication is deemed valid by the 2FA process, can X be used to address the server inside the firewall.

Obviously, I don't want some renegade user simply downloading X from the web, installing it, then running it and getting to the server.  But since X is a COTS and I have no access to the code, I just don't seen how to add 2FA to its use.

Am I barking up a tree without a critter in it, or is there something I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

There is one company called TeleSign which specializes in [two factor authentication](http://www.telesign.com/products-demos/telesign-2fa) solutions. I think they will be able to add a 2FA module to your COTS program.

Comment: #TeleSign is a fake company actually. Don't bother for it.

Comment: As you have this only post on SA, it seems you are self-promoting telesign. No?